# Unable to generate a recovery key

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, recovery

I am using an iPhone 12 (iOS 16.3.1) and would like to turn on ADP for iCloud. In order to do that, I need to create a recovery key but whenever I try I get this error:

```
Account Not Eligible
Your account is not eligible to use a recovery key.
```

I’ve tried looking through Apple support docs but I have yet to find anything that enumerates the requirements for an account to be eligible to generate a recovery key.

Some other details

- I do not have a recovery contact
- I have a trusted phone number
- Two factor authentication is turned on

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It's perfectly fine to ask us to guess / relate - but [this is the sort of thing that Apple Support excels](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2508/5472) in - they are in the best position to look at your account and guide you quickly to resolution.

Comment: I was hoping someone else had ran into this issue before and had an idea, or perhaps I missed something in the documentation https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208072 Thanks to the meta link, I know that the error says “account” but if say hanging two Apple devices was a requirement that missed, it would answer my question

Comment: I will try and reach out support and answer my own question if the process could work for someone else

Comment: Self answering from experience is super awesome. My hunch is TFA needs two devices to allow this, but three would be better IMO. +1 for the question it's clear and having it documented here will be useful.

Comment: My first round with support resulted in them having to call me back, the agent asked if I had 2FA enabled (which I do) but that seemed about the extent of what they could do. I hope I don’t need two Apple devices to use ADP, but if I do, it will be nice for that to get documented somewhere. I’ve got a hardware key but when I tried enrolling that, it said I needed two so Apple might want some redundancy

Comment: Is two-factor verification turned on?

Comment: Did you get the [legacy Two Step](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204152) or the [new Two Factor](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915)? If purely the latter, you may be very much correct - multiple devices signed in would be the logical trigger to block you.

Comment: I may have an answer but you first need to tell me if two-factor verification is turned on.

Comment: I am not sure how to tell if I have the legacy two step or the new tow factor. @Thinkr I updated the question to include the fact I do have two-factor turned on.

Comment: Do *all* of your devices signing into iCloud meet the requirements?  See “System Requirements” at this link:  https://support.apple.com/guide/security/advanced-data-protection-for-icloud-sec973254c5f/web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with the inability to add a recovery key and security keys as well, and I worked with Apple support for about a week of back and forth conversations until I heard back from the engineering department. Basically, it was a syncing issue; Apple servers think that the device doesn't have a passcode setup on it and obviously that wasn't true, and I had it setup. All we had to do was disable the passcode and find my, reboot the device so that it would sync correctly, and then enable them back and try to add the recovery key and the security keys. My theory was that I needed another trusted device, but that was not correct. I hope my answer helps you.